# How to create custom image decorator in java file using eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I would like to use some decorators in my Eclipse plugin. I have created a plugin where I created my own editor for my own .test file. If the user edits .test file and saves it. The file must show some decorations not only the .test file but also the project must show the decorator. I am stuck with this problem I can't find any good tutorial to create decorators.

I Have seen some of the websites like https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Decorators/decorators.html but I couldn't get the exact point.

Will some one please tell me how to create custom decorator for my eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ILightweightLabelDecorator` is the most common type of decorator

Declare this in your plugin.xml with something like this:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.decorators"> 
    <decorator
        id="my.decorator.id" 
        class="my.decorator.Decorator" 
        label="My Decorator" 
        state="true" 
        lightweight="true" 
        adaptable="true"> 
        <enablement>
            <objectClass name="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource"/> 
        </enablement>
    </decorator>
</extension>
```

You will have to adjust the enablement to suit what you want.

Your decorator class would be something like:

```java
public class Decorator extends BaseLabelDecorator implements ILightweightLabelDecorator
{
  @Override
  public void decorate(final Object element, final IDecoration decoration)
  {
    // TODO call decoration methods to add overlay images or prefix / suffix text
  }
}
```

Comment: But, how to check whether file is a .test file and then apply a decorator? And where to do this check?

Comment: @VarunRaval You look at the `element` object passed to the `decorate` method. Ask a new question if you need more details.

Comment: element object is a representative of file only or something else too? And how to get that file?